# Change name of workspace in terraform cloud

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cloud

I have few terraform workspaces for which I want to change the name of it, I am not sure if I should straight forward go to settings and change the name or it will impact any state? this may look a stupid question but I am not finding any specific answer to it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

When you change the name of your directory, it has no impact on the remote infrastructure. However be careful with the absolute path of your modules.

Comment: What do you mean by not using local files in the script. which script are we talking there? the file that are in a work space does use local.tf

Comment: I mean if you don't use /folder1/folder2/youDirectory/files.tf in jenkins or other it will be fine for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).